New post doesn't appear under old post
So I am creating a page where a user can add details to a post and posted it, but when I try to add a new post nothing happens. Here it's the video of the issue : https://imgur.com/a/D2qoOSu , here it's the page where you add detail for the post :
class WorkoutContentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const WorkoutContentPage({super.key});

  @override
  WorkoutContentPageState createState() => WorkoutContentPageState();
}

class WorkoutContentPageState extends State<WorkoutContentPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map>>? stream;
  String? userId;
  String? nameprogram;
  String? typeprogram;
  String? typeequipment;
  TextEditingController nameprogramController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController typeprogramController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController typeequipmentController = TextEditingController();

  XFile? image;

  Future pickImage() async {
    try {
      image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('Failed to pick image: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(userId)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      var data = value.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      nameprogram = data["nameprogram"];
      typeprogram = data["typeprogram"];
      typeequipment = data["typeequipment"];

      // Populate TextEditingControllers with existing data
      nameprogramController.text = nameprogram ?? '';
      typeprogramController.text = typeprogram ?? '';
      typeequipmentController.text = typeequipment ?? '';
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controllers when the widget is disposed
    nameprogramController.dispose();
    typeprogramController.dispose();
    typeequipmentController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Workout Content',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Center(
                child: Column(children: [
              Text(
                'Add details about your entire workout program',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: nameprogramController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Name of the program",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: typeprogramController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Type of program(ex: strength, cardio, yoga",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: typeequipmentController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Type of equipment used",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  fillColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                  filled: true,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 250,
                height: 70,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    pickImage();
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "+Add photo/video for cover",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Text(
                  'We suggest you to do a short video of 10-15 sec with some exercise that your program has so the user can get an idea of what to expect'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 250,
                height: 70,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => WorkoutContentPage()),
                    );
                  },
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    "Set price",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240),
        child: Container(
          width: 50,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(userId).set({
                  "nameprogram": nameprogramController.text,
                  "typeprogram": typeprogramController.text,
                  "typeequipment": typeequipmentController.text,
                }).then((_) {
                  // Navigate to the user profile page
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => UserProfilePage(
                              imageFile: File(image!.path),
                            )),
                  );
                });
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Continue',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
    // ignore: dead_code
  }

  void _alertNoText(BuildContext context) {
    Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.warning,
      title: "Post",
      desc: "You have not written any text",
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          width: 120,
          child: const Text(
            "Close",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ).show();
  }
}

class UserProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final imageFile;

  const UserProfilePage({super.key, this.imageFile});

  @override
  State<UserProfilePage> createState() => _UserProfilePageState();
}

class _UserProfilePageState extends State<UserProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('User Profile'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future:
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(userId).get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Center(child: Text('Error fetching data'));
          }

          if (!snapshot.hasData || !snapshot.data!.exists) {
            return const Center(child: Text('No data found'));
          }

          final data = snapshot.data!.data()!;
          final nameprogram = data["nameprogram"];
          final typeprogram = data["typeprogram"];
          final typeequipment = data["typeequipment"];

          return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 10, right: 10),
              child: Container(
                  height: 135,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius:
                            new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(10))),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shadows: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        spreadRadius: 2,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    widget.imageFile != null
                        ? Image.file(
                            widget.imageFile,
                            height: 80,
                            width: 80,
                          )
                        : Text("No image selected"),

                    const SizedBox(width: 10), // space between image & Column
                    Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 25,
                        ),
                        Text('$nameprogram',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        Text('type: $typeprogram',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey)),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 5,
                        ),
                        Text('equipment: $typeequipment',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.grey)),
                      ],
                    )),
                  ])));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

And on this code it's also added the page where the post appears. What I should change to the code so there can be added more posts to the user profile
